# How can I create my own list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I would like to create my own list in Haskell where I could put in the number 6 and get the result [1,2,3,4,5,6]

I thought I could write something like

```
ones :: Int ->  [a]
ones 0 = []
ones n = [n, n-1 ... n==0]
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: `ones n = [1..n]`

Comment: Why would you call this function `ones`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Below a non-exhaustive list.

You can use Haskells list ranges:

```
ones :: (Enum n, Num n) -> n -> [n]
ones n = [1 .. n]
```

You can use the [**`enumFromTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromTo) function:

```
ones :: (Enum n, Num n) -> n -> [n]
ones = enumFromTo 1
```

Or we can use explicit recursion:

```
ones :: (Ord n, Num n) => n -> [n]
ones n = go 1
    where go i | i <= n = i : go (i+1)
               | otherwise = []
```

Or by using [**`iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) and [**`take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take):

```
ones :: Num n => Int -> [n]
ones n = take n (iterate (1+) 1)
```

Note that not all approaches have the same signature. Some implementations do not require the numerical type to be an instance of the [**`Enum`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) type class, which can make the function more flexible in the sense that numerical types that can not be enumerated, can still get processed.

Comment: I think `unfoldr` is worth mentioning. Also, `Num` isn't strictly more general than `Enum`, as things like `Ordering` and `Bool` show.

Comment: `scanl` is `f n = scanl (\b a -> b+a) 1 $ replicate (n-1) 1`